# Why can 'CURRENT_DATE' not as a parameter when using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

In mysql,I use this sql and it runs well.

`select * from student where CREATE_TIME>=DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)`

Now I want to use the date as a parameter,SO I use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`,If I pass the date like '2020-05-30',it also runs well.But when I pass 'CURRENT_DATE' or 'curdate()',it could not search any result.How to change my code?

```
 NamedParameterJdbcTemplate nameJdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //dateStr when '2020-05-30' is ok,'CURRENT_DATE' is not ok;     
   paramMap.put("dateStr",dateStr); 
    String sql = "SELECT *"
            + " FROM student where CREATE_TIME>=DATE_SUB(:dateStr,INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" ;
    return   nameJdbc.query(sql,paramMap,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Student.class));
```

Comment: Calculate the current date in your code and pass that

Comment: @juergend,CURRENT_DATE is mysql server time,and new date() is the application server time

Comment: Why do you want to use it as a parameter? If that is not a string that could change, why not write it in the query?

Comment: And those 2 times should be in sync anyway. Besides `current_date` does not even contain time

Comment: @NicoHaase,because the select time is a parameter,it could be changed by user.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is the Spring JdbcTemplate, not JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the `CURRENT_DATE`, or an equivalent function call is being inserted as a string parameter, and not as a keyword.

One thing you could do is to manually replace the `:dateStr` in the SQL string with `CURRENT_DATE` if the parameter is empty, otherwise put its value in the parameter map.

A better option would be to just use `LocalDate.now().toString()` to set the date string, if the parameter is empty, and always set it in the SQL statement.